# Mostrar datos de JSON en fila HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera saber de qué manera pudiese acomodar la información de un `JSON` que recibo en una sola fila con diferentes columnas, aunque lo que recibo es en una sola columna, cada dato del `JSON` sería una columna en palabras más sencillas.

El código de mi Script es mas o menos así:

```
$.ajax({

  data: datos,
  url: 'views/acueducto.php',
  method: "POST",
  timeout: 0,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },

  error: function (xhr, status) {
    alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
  },
  sucess: console.log("funcionando")
}).done(function (respuesta) {
  var url = "views/acueducto.php";
  $("#tablajson tbody").html("");

  npozos = JSON.parse(respuesta);

  $.each(npozos, function (i, npozo) {
    var newRow =
      "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + npozo.datos + "</td>"

      +
      "</tr>";
    $(newRow).appendTo("#tablajson tbody");
  });
```

La información del `JSON` la recibo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado que obtengo con ese código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, edita la pregunta y añade el codigo html para poder tener un ejemplo minimamente ejecutable, si no va a ser dificil darte una respuesta concreta

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en la plataforma pero tratare de mejorar en las publicaciones!

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, te sugiero marcarla como útil con el check que hay al lado izquierdo, bajo los botones para votar. Con esto, ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad y la respuesta puede servir de referencia para futuros visitantes que tengan un problema similar al tuyo. Adicionalmente, te sugiero [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas sacar el `tr` del ciclo `.each`. De este modo creas una sola fila y dentro del ciclo dejas los `td`, que son los que realmente interesa iterar. Luego pasas toda la fila maquetada a la tabla del `html`.

```
npozos = JSON.parse(respuesta);
var newRow = "<tr>";
$.each(npozos, function (i, npozo) {
   newRow += "<td>" + npozo.datos + "</td>";
});
newRow += "</tr>";
$("#tablajson tbody").append(newRow);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, al parecer ese era el error que no había visto!